# How to make sure a function in PHP finishes before the user clicks on another link?

Tags: php, function

I am creating an online judge. I am using the IDEONE API to compile the file. So when my user uploads a file, there is a function which takes the file and compiles the file using the IDEONE API. But the problem is while the file is being compiled, if my user clicks on a new link, the compilation remains half-finished. Is there a way to make sure the function executes completely before the user redirects?

My first idea was to create a thread and make the thread do the compilation. And while the thread is running, I could show the user a new view. But apparently you cannot run a thread in PHP, so I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, there's really no way to make sure a user stays on the page while something completes.

Your best bet is pass your compilation job to a background process. One way to do it would be to insert a row into a database with the information you'd like to process. You can them immediately show the user a message stating their job has been placed in the queue, and will be processed soon. Then set up a [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to grab the information out of the database, and make the request to your API. When it's done, you update the database again to indicate the job is done. If it's a particularly long running process, you can email the user that their job has completed so they don't have to sit and wait.

Overall your goal is give the user good feedback about what's happening while not running your process in a way that can be lost by the user navigating away.